# Convert Tweet string in text file to JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json, twitter

Here is an example string I have stored in a `txt` file called `file.txt`:

```
{
    "created_at":"Wed Mar 30 23:13:12 +0000 2013",
    "id":3712307838977,
    "id_str":"12307838977",
    "timestamp_ms":"7392180”
}
```

This data is related to tweets and each tweet is on a new line of the text file.

Right now I am loading it into python with the following code:

```
with open(test_file, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
```

This gives me a list of strings for each tweet. I would like to convert it to a json object so I could do something like:

```
for tweet in data:
    created = tweet["created_at']
```

However I've gotten many different types of errors when attempting to use `json.loads(tweet)`. Any assisstance?

Comment: Can you share your error message(s) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are most likely happening is because this part of your string:

```
"timestamp_ms":"7392180”
```

More specifically, that last quote `”`

You are most likely getting this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 105 (char 104)
```

I don't know how you generated this file, but by fixing that and using this double quote `"` the conversion works.

```
import json

with open('new_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    json_data = json.loads(f.read().strip())


for data in json_data:
    print(json_data[data])
```

---

Output:

```
3712307838977
12307838977
7392180
Wed Mar 30 23:13:12 +0000 2013
```

Comment: Thanks @idjaw! Frustrating to get stuck for so long on a small error, but I do have it working now.